# Want to disable my bootstrap carousel autoplay

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I'm using a website template (https://p.w3layouts.com/demos/hallooou/one-page.html) and it as a cool carousel that I want to keep!
The thing is that I want no disable all off the events that make it ran by itself (autoplay, events triggered by mouse events,...) so that only the user can ran through the carousel!

I've tried almost everything but as I understand little of JAVA if you could be specific using the same template as I, it would be really nice!
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Try to add code

Answer (score 1):

Use `interval` with `false`

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 6000
});
```